# how to keep some special metrics for prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I use the following config for Prometheus, and found no `go_info` and `go_gc_duration_seconds` metrics:

## config1

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     60s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 3s

    metric_relabel_configs:
    - action: keep
      source_labels:
      - __name__
      regex: go_info

    - action: keep
      source_labels:
      - __name__
      regex: go_gc_duration_seconds

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']
```

when using the following config, I can found `go_info` and `go_gc_duration_seconds` metrics:

## config2

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     60s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'ssli-prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 3s

    metric_relabel_configs:
    - action: keep
      source_labels:
      - __name__
      regex: go_info|go_gc_duration_seconds

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']
```

if I want to keep a lot of metrics, I must add these metrics to `regex` fields, like this:

```
    metric_relabel_configs:
    - action: keep
      source_labels:
      - __name__
      regex: metrcis1|metrcis2|metrcis3|metrcis4......|metrcisN
```

I worried regex is too long, so can I config multiple `keep` action to keep these metrics? like this：

```
    metric_relabel_configs:
    - action: keep
      source_labels:
      - __name__
      regex: metrics1
    - action: keep
      source_labels:
      - __name__
      regex: metrics2
    - action: keep
      source_labels:
      - __name__
      regex: metrics3
      ...
    - action: keep
      source_labels:
      - __name__
      regex: metricsN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus supports [RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

You can simplify your config by using regex. The following expression selects all metrics that have a name starting with `metrics`(ie. metrics1,metrics2,....,metricsN).

```yaml
    - action: keep
      source_labels:
      - __name__
      regex: "metrics.*"
```

- [Instant vector selectors](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors)

Comment: thanks, we can use a regex you point above, if these metrics have not a name starting with `metrics`, do you know how to config it? (ie. build_info, go_info,....,total_cpus).

Comment: @LEo find a label that is common in all the metrics that you want to keep. Filter upon on that specif label instead of the metric name.